# Magento 2 Redis Clean old tags

Tags: magento2, redis

I have a script for my Magento 1 stores to clean old Redis keys:

```
<?php 

  count($argc) or die('<pre>:P</pre>');
  ini_set('memory_limit','1024M');
  set_time_limit(0);
  error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
  require_once '../app/Mage.php';
  Mage::app()->getCache()->getBackend()->clean('old');

?>
```

which I run every night with a cron job. Can I use the same script for Magento 2?